# Is the map $f:(x^1, \dots, x^n) \mapsto (x^1, \dots, x^{i - 1}, x^{i + 1}, \dots, x^{n})$ a projection?

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$ be defined by

$$
f:(x^1, \dots, x^n) \mapsto (x^1, \dots, x^{i - 1}, x^{i + 1}, \dots, x^{n}).
$$

Is this map a projection map? I know we can give $\mathbb{R}^n$ the product topology as a product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$, and there's an isomorphism between that space and $\mathbb{R}^{i - 1} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n - (i + 1)}$. If not, is there a name for a vector-valued function where you've omitted one of the parameters?

Comment: Yes, this is what most people would call a projection. Or are you thinking about a more "precise" definition of projection map?

Comment: I was thinking of the definition being map that takes an element of a product space to it's $i$-th component. But the confusion partly lies in the fact that other things seem to sometimes be referred to as projections.

Answer (score 3):

A projection of a vector space $V$ is to a subspace of $V.$ (That’s not the full definition, but it is part of it.) Since $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^n,$ then technically, your map can’t be a projection.

There are lots of ways to make $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^n.$ Under some isomorphisms, your map is a projection. Under others,  your map is not.

I’m not sure if there is a name for such a function, but it is not a primary class of functions we tend to study in linear algebra, because it depends on one basis of the vector space.

If your function were $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ and changed the $i$th entry to zero, rather than removing it, then the function would be a projection. (That seems to be what you are getting at with the factorization of $\mathbb R^n.$)

**Theorem:** Given any projection, $T:V\to V,$ there is a basis of your vector space such that the projection just zeroes out a fixed set of coordinates.

**Proof:** Let $$U=\{v\in V\mid Tv=0\}$$ and $$W=\{v\in V\mid Tv=v\}.$$ Then every $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as $u+w$ where $u\in U,w\in W.$

Given $V,$ we can take $u=v-Tv$ and $w=Tv.$

On the other hand, if $v=u_1+w_1=u_2+w_2$ then $$w_1=T(u_1+w_1)=T(u_2+w_2)=w_2.$$

So we can take $e_1,\dots,e_k$ as a basis for $W$ and $e_{k+1},\dots,e_n$ a basis for $U.$ Then $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are a basis for $V$ and $$T(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n)=a_1e_1+\cdots +a_ke_k.$$

Answer (score 3):

"Projection" is indeed used in several different senses. It seems you are talking about topological quotients (which are also referred to as projections in topology).

For a map $\pi\colon X\to Y$ between topological spaces to be a topological quotient, it needs to be surjective, and have the property that $A\subseteq Y$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is open.

You can easily show that your map is continuous and surjective, so the only nontrivial part in showing that it is a topological quotient is proving that if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

What you can do is prove that $f$ is an open map (consider open cubes for this), and then use the fact that $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$, which follows from surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: It isn't quite obvious to me how you'd show this map is continuous. Can give a sketch of the proof?

Comment: @bxw In general, whenever you have topological spaces $X_1,\ldots,X_{k-1},X_k,X_{k+1},\ldots,X_n$, the maps $p\colon \prod_{i=1}^n X_i\to \prod_{i\neq k}X_i$, $(x_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}\mapsto (x_i)_{i\neq k}$ is continuous: A basic open set of $\prod_{i\neq k}X_i$ has the form $U=\prod_{i\neq k}U_i$, where the $U_i$ (defined for $i\neq k$) are open in $X_i$, and $p^{-1}(U)=\prod_{i=1}^n U_i$, where we set $U_k=X_k$. Thus preimages of basic open sets are open, and since preimages preserve unions, the same is valid for open sets, so $p$ is continuous.